# Modify array elements using other elements

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble figuring out my output isn't doing the correct thing.  This is the piece of code I wrote for

```
         final int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
      int[] bonusScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
      int i;

      for (i = 0; i < bonusScores.length; ++i) {
         bonusScores[i] = scnr.nextInt();
      }


for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
   bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i+1]; 
}
      for (i = 0; i < bonusScores.length; ++i) {
         System.out.print(bonusScores[i] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

right now im getting an output of |20 30 40 40| instead of |30 50 70 40|. I'm getting the error in my second for loop but im not sure how to correct it.

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Why do you expect to get the output that you posted? What are you intending to have done?

Comment: im just trying to modify the array elements i mean its in the title:P

Comment: What input are you providing in your terminal? It is not immediately clear where the numbers come from. Please provide these details to help others understand your problem better.

Comment: the numbers being inputted are 10, 20, 30, 40, forgot to mention that

Comment: Then why do you expect the output to be 30, 50, 70, 40? In your code, you are doing bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i+1], which means "set i'th element equal to i+1'th". In other words, you are just 'bringing' 2nd, 3rd, 4th elements to one place left, and also leaving 4th element unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
   bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i+1]; 
}
```

is doing exactly what you're telling it to do: copy the second element over the first, the third over the second, etc. so [10,20,30,40] becomes [20,20,30,40].

I'm guessing that you meant to do `+=` instead of `=` from your description of the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably too late but this is what my code looks like:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
{
    bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i] + bonusScores[i+1]; 
}
```

**I added bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i] + bonusScores[i+1]**

or just add +=